# Error on apt update: unable to connect to ftp.it.debian.org:http:

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, apt

I have Debian Wheezy with kernel 3.2.0-3-amd64.

Suddenly, from this morning (I'm italian), it's impossibile to correctly update the system via `apt-get update`.

The system hangs on backport mirror `deb http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main`, but 'till yesterday everything went well !

Any suggestions to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mirror seems down. See http://mirror.debian.org/status.html

I recommend to use another one. Just replace `ftp.it.debian.org` with another debian mirror, for example: `ftp.de.debian.org`.

Here are the exact error codes from the above status page:

- 17: ERROR: 500 LWP::Protocol::MyFTP: connect: timeout
- 24: ERROR: 500 Can't connect to ftp.it.debian.org:80 (timeout)
- 25: rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(122) [Receiver=3.0.9]